# Why does the series not converge to its actual value?

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion

I am uncertain why does the taylor series expansion of $\ln(x)$ $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}(x-1)^n}{n}$$ at $x = 2$ has almost the same value with the actual value of $\ln(2)$. However, the sum of the taylor series expansion of $\log_3(2x-1)$ which is $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}(2^n)(x-1)^n}{(n)(\log3)}$$ at $x = 2$ is not even almost equal to the value of $\log_3(3)$. The actual value is $1$, but the value of $$\sum^{10}_{n=1} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}(2^n)(x-1)^n}{(n)(\log3)}$$ is around $-100$. The sum, a negative value, increases as the order of the summation increases. What is the reason behind this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It being $\log_3$ is irrelevant, you can forget about that part. The point is that the expansion of $\ln(2x-1)$ about $x=1$ evaluated at $x=2$ is the same series as for the expansion of $\ln(y)$ about $y=2 \cdot 1 - 1 =1$ evaluated at $y=2 \cdot 2-1=3$, which is outside the interval of convergence of the series, which is to say $(0,2]$.